# filter javascript listing with an age range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to be able to search for an age range e.g 10-20 from an input field and get a result of who is in that search, their name and age.

this is how my data is structured

```
var customers = [
{
    name: "Rocky Green",
    birthdate: "1988-10-01"
},
{
    name: "Sara Pink",
    birthdate: "1982-03-15"
},
{
    name: "Tom Black",
    birthdate: "1995-01-25"
},
]
```

This the code i currently have which calculates the age from a date string

```
function getAge(dateString) 
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
        {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }
    getAge("1995-01-25");
    console.log(getAge("1995-01-25"));
```

But this a little advanced for me.

Comment: `customers.filter(c => { let age = getAge(c.birthdate); return 10 <= age && age <= 20 });`

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [array `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array that contains only the elements that match your condition.

The following does that (using your existing `getAge()` function). For demo purposes I've just used a simple button and input accessed via `.querySelector()` without bothering with element IDs or anything, and I haven't included any input validation - in your real project you'd want to add some code to make sure the user entered a valid range.

Given a string `"10-20"`, you can extract the "10" and the "20" by using the [string `.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), splitting on the `"-"`. The result of that will be an array containing the two numbers *as strings*, so I've converted these to numbers using the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) so that they can be compared to the age of each person.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var range = document.querySelector("input").value.split("-")
  var lower = +range[0]
  var upper = +range[1]
  var results = customers.filter(function(v) {
    var age = getAge(v.birthdate)
    return age >= lower && age <= upper
  })
  console.log(results)
})

var customers = [
  { name: "Rocky Green", birthdate: "1988-10-01" },
  { name: "Sara Pink", birthdate: "1982-03-15" },
  { name: "Tom Black", birthdate: "1995-01-25" }
]

function getAge(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}
```

```html
<label>Age range: <input value="10-30"></label>
<button>Filter</button>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, This is Awesome! Now i just have to display the results neatly and also convert the returned birthdate to an age .